# Удалить датафрейм из списка датафреймов

Tags: python, dataframe

Имеется список датафреймов, в котором встречаются датафреймы с 1 столбцом, которые нужно удалить

Пытаюсь сделать так

```
for table in dfs:
    if table.shape[1] == 1:
        ind = ([i for i in range(0, table.shape[0])])
        table.drop(ind)
```

Но это не работает

Хотелось бы полностью удалять такие датафреймы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если тебе нужно просто отфильтровать датафреймы с одним столбцом, то просто сделай так:

```
dfs = [table for table in dfs if table.shape[1] != 1]
```